# wso2 cep input adapter keeps running after shutdown issued

Tags: java, wso2, rabbitmq, wso2-cep

Hi I have an input adapter that reads messages off a rabbitmq queue. I see that when the server starts, a subscribe() call is made on the adapter. But when the wso2 server is being shutdown, i dont see a unsubscribe() call being made. This is making the adapter read and remove messages till the jvm dies - even though the other components of the cep seem to be down. Has anybody else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have not encountered this issue so far but I think there is a possibility that above issue can occur.. We'll consider this for next release to fix it. Can you please raise a jira  [1] on this.. For the moment, you can overcome this issue by unsubscribing the call back in the deactivate() method of the adaptor that you written. You can implement as below

protected void deactivate(ComponentContext context);

Check for OSGI docs for more info.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP